# Load Data Local Infile with Zend Framework and PDO Adapter

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo

im switching from native PHP to Zend Framework and need a script doing a **Load Data Local Infile** to a database on a separated server.

I'm changing my application.ini to

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.host ="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 
resources.db.params.username = "yyyyyyy"
resources.db.params.password = "zzzzzzz"
resources.db.params.dbname = "xyxyxyxy"
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
resources.db.params.driver_options.PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE=1;
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

and trying

```
resources.db.params.driver_options.1001=1;
```

too.

I create the db object by

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

and sending a query using Load data local infile to the database.
The result ist following error

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I use the same query native by php mysql functions but connecting with the client_flag 128. Without this client flag i get the same error.

So, how could i use Local Infile with Zend Framework and PDO?

Answer (score 2):

```
resources.db.params.driver_options.1001 = true;
```

should work, you cant use CONSTANTS in application.ini.
Please try "true" instead of "1"

Comment: NB: The following values are truthy values: `null`, `no` and `false` result in `""`, `yes` and `true` result in `"1"`. (From [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file#refsect1-function.parse-ini-file-notes))

Answer (score 0):

I m trying to hunt down the same thing.. 
I have tried adding

[mysql]
local-infile

[mysqld]
local-infile

which should fix the problem on ubuntu 12.04 according to some users (but didn't for me)
there is also a php bug but should be fixed a long time ago: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54158

Reading this post: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data-local.html#c3237 he claims it can be fixed by recompiling but i didn't try it.